PRTG - Invalid JSON structure Error PE231
I am very new to PRTG and VEEAM ect. so please do bare with me
I've seen this error been talked about a lot, but nothing has helped me so far. I have a custom XML script that I use for VEEAM backup (https://github.com/vMarkusK/Advanced-PRTG-Sensors)
I get the following error:
XML: The returned XML does not match the expected schema. (code: PE233) -- JSON: The returned JSON does not match the expected structure (Invalid JSON.). (code: PE231)
From what I can tell the problem won't be with the actual code, no one else seems to have this problem.
When I manually run the script through powershell, it doesn't seem to give any errors.
I have deleted the script we had on the server, and replaced it with the latest one from github, I also created a new sensor (didn't delete the old one since I don't want to loose the current historical data) and the same problem came up.
The script seemed to have failed with no interference that we are aware of.
Anyone have any advice on how I can solve this?
